# How to make DataGrip default to using Manual transactions?

Tags: database, transactions, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

My team uses DataGrip to interact with production databases, and we'd like to enforce the use of transactions for all db changes. I know how to toggle on `Tx: Manual`, which then forces transactions for that session, but the next time I open DataGrip, it defaults back to `Tx: Auto`. I can't find anything in the docs or settings to change the default. Does anyone know a way to make this happen?

Here are the docs I've been referencing: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/configuring-database-connections.html#transaction-mode

Tried setting Tx to Manual mode: works for one session but toggles off the next time I open DataGrip

Tried searching the app settings and couldn't find a way to change the default.

Tried searching the docs and came up dry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to se it for the whole data source in its properties:

[image]